# Prevent Dojo Caching ItemFileWriteStore Data

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I'm working on a web page which uses Dojo's EnhancedGrid to allow the user to edit data and save it to the server.  I have the edit and saving correctly however the grid always shows the old value of the cell if I refresh the page.  If I close the window and open it again then I get the new value.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the grid to update the row after you have saved something to the server. Here is what my callback method looks like.

```
function onApplyCellEditHandler(inGrid, inValue, inRowIndex, inFieldIndex) {
        inGrid.store.save({onError: errorSaving});
        inGrid.updateRow(inRowIndex);
}
```

I've also had issues with another mechanism updated data and the grid not seeing those results. In other words, user A loads the grid then user B loads the grid. User A makes a change and then user B reloads the grid. Only user B doesn't see user A's change. You'll need to make a call to grid.update() to tell the grid to completely refresh with the new data supplied by the call to fetch.